# How to change project properties in Xamarin.Android project to run on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge SM-G925F

Tags: xamarin, dll, target-platform

Hey I have included a library to my Xamarin.Android project and and my function works on my emulator Android_Accelerated x86 Oreo but not on my real device Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge SM-G925F.

I get Errors that there is a mismatch between my processor architecture and my targeted processor architecture. When I go to project properties > Android Options then there are several Platforms to select. I have tried many combinations but its still not matching. There are also many options to (de-)select but I am not sure ablout how to change it.

The current Error is have is:
There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Users\madiguez\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\accelerometer2\accelerometer2\bin\x64\Debug\accelerometer2.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project

[image]

[image]

[image: Android Options > Advanced]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Samsung Galaxy s6 runs on armeabi-v7a abi so you might wanna add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use armeabi-v7a for architecture configuration.
according
http://www.greenbagpipes.com/samsung_galaxy_s6_edge